# What is the reason C++ std IO doesn't output NULL gracefully?

Tags: c++, stdio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does std::cout output disappear completely after NULL is sent to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019454/why-does-stdcout-output-disappear-completely-after-null-is-sent-to-it)

It seems if you try:

```
 std::cout << NULL << endl;
 std::cout << "hell" << endl;
```

it print out nothing and C++ IO stops working for all subsequent outputs.

but it works fine in C stdio:

```
 printf("%s\n", NULL);
 printf("%s\n", "hell");
```

> (null)
>
> hell

Is there any good reason why C++ IO can't do the same thing?

(edited in response to comments)
alright, to make it clear, NULL does have a type, say const char*

```
const char* getxxx();  // may return NULL, 
cout << getxxx();      // won't work if NULL returned
```

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure that the standard defines how `printf` handles a null pointer for `%s`.

Comment: Is this the ACTUAL code you are referrring to, or are you actually doing something else. And I agree with Oli - printf isn't defined to handle NULL - in fact it may well NOT handle it.

Comment: `std::cout << NULL << endl;` [works just fine](http://ideone.com/QkGMNp). I think you mean something more like [`std::cout << (char*)NULL << endl;`](http://ideone.com/IeBdeJ).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It doesn't; it's undefined behavior.  But he's not talking about a null pointer; his examples pass a null pointer constant, which isn't a pointer (and on my machine, doesn't even have the same size as a pointer).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Huh?  I see no reason why `cout` should fail simply because you executed

```
std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
```

It should output `0\n`.  And [it does](http://ideone.com/qH0wZD).  End of story.

(In case you're confused, please know that in C++, `#define NULL (0)`.)

In case you wrote:

```
T* p = 0;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

then it will display the address `0`, (generally in hexadecimal and padded to the pointer size, since this is the preferred way of looking at pointers).

(This is btw the behavior you would get using the C definition of NULL, which is `#define NULL ((void*)0)`.)

Only if you write

```
char* p = 0;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

are you in trouble.  Now you're calling

> ```
> template<class traits>
> basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out, const char* s);
> ```

for which the Standard (section 27.7.3.6.4) says:

> *Requires*: `s` shall not be a null pointer.

When you do pass a null pointer, the rule 17.6.4.9 applies, which states that:

> Each of the following applies to all arguments to functions deﬁned in the C++ standard library, unless explicitly stated otherwise.
>   * If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function or a pointer invalid for its intended use), the behavior is undefined.

So you're in the land of "undefined behavior".  There's no guarantee that `failbit` gets set and the program continues.

---

Please note that `printf` behavior didn't actually depend on the type of `NULL`.  It's the format string `"%s"` that caused treatment as a string (pointer to NUL-terminated character sequence).

Comment: Is `NULL` really guaranteed to be defined as `0`? AFAIK, implementations are free to define it e.g. as `0L`

Comment: @AndyProwl True, but can you tell the difference between `cout << 0` and `cout << 0L` at runtime? :)

Comment: @Andy: ok, so `std::cout << 0L << std::endl;`.  Which also outputs `0\n`.

Comment: I'm not questioning whether or not it should output `0`, that's obvious. I was just clarifying a statement that was slightly imprecise. It makes no difference in this case, but it may make a difference in other cases.

Comment: What about the more general case, e.g. `const char *getString() { return NULL; } ... cout << getString()`?

Comment: @Oli: That's a different question, clearly.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Indeed.  But based on the OP's edits, I think that's what's really being asked!

Comment: @arrows: `NULL` is a constant integral expression with value `0`.  The type is one of the types allowed for constant integral expressions (e.g. `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, etc)

Comment: @Ben Voigt how in general `cout << (const char*) NULL` works in C++? and what is the difference between the definition of NULL in C and C++? I *am* confused, is it defined to be something else other than 0 in C?

Comment: @arrows: Now I've answered the three questions you didn't ask.  Is that helpful?

Comment: +1 for the standard quote

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yes, indeed helpful

Comment: @arrows There's not a fundamental difference between C and C++ here.  The C standard gives a little more leeway for non-traditional definitions of `NULL`, but nothing which would make a significant different.

Comment: `There's no guarantee that failbit gets set and the program continues.` And, when it does, failbit is set, so nothing else is accepted into the stream. I covered this somewhere before.

Comment: [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7019483/560648)

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%s", str)` is not required to handle `NULL` strings, so by passing `NULL`  you are asking for trouble.

The semantically equivalent statement with IOStreams is:

```
std::cout << static_cast<char const*>(NULL);
```

And this is not required to handle `NULL` string either.

Comment: It's important to remember that `"%s"` requires a `char*` as argument; unlike the C++ version, it doesn't know the type.  And `NULL` is _not_ a `char*`; it's an integral type; in the environment in which I currently work, `sizeof(NULL)` and `sizeof(char*)` have different values.