# Program stops working after printing argv

Tags: c++, argv

I wrote some basic code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    for (int i=1;i<=argc;i++){
        cout << argv[i] <<"\n";
    }
    cout <<"hello";

    return 0;
}
```

and when i'm running it for example with

```
./a.out 1 2 3
```

I see:

```
1
2
3
```

Why there's no "hello"?

Comment: Probably because you're shy a `flush`.

Comment: replace `i<=argc` with `i<argc`

Comment: @Rubens: No, streams are flushed on program end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop tries to stream `argv[argc]`, which is one *after* your program arguments.

In fact, it is defined to be a null pointer<sup>1</sup>, and giving streams a null pointer sets their error bit<sup>2</sup>.

Consequently, your next stream operation (`cout << "hello"`) fails.

**Loop up to `argc` *but not including it*:**

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    cout << argv[i] << '\n';
}
```

---

#### Footnote 1

> `[C++11: 3.6.1/2]:` *[..]* The value of `argv[argc]` shall be 0. *[..]*

#### Footnote 2

> `[C++11: 27.7.3.6.4/3]:` Requires: `s` shall not be a null pointer

When it is, the behaviour is undefined; GCC chooses to trap the condition and set the stream's error bit — see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019483/560648.

Comment: and, of course, argv[0] is the name of the executable. which is why the first argument is at an un-C-like "1".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Are you joking?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, definitely not

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'm sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 1):

you're referencing argv[argc] which is beyond the array.

Change your for statement to:

```
for (int i=1;i<argc;i++){
```