# Usage of dlsym()/dlopen()

Tags: c++, posix, symbols

I wrote next program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef void* (*fptr)();
    fptr func;
    void *handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW);
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;    
    *(void **)(&func) = dlsym(handle, "__libc_start_main");
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;

    std::cout << handle << " " << func << "\n";

    dlclose(handle);
return 0;
}
```

and try to compile in next way:

```
g++ -rdynamic main.cpp -ldl -o test
```

When I run this program I don’t see any message. Why?

Thank U for attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your process is faulting because `dlerror()` is only valid to call in an *error* condition, which you never validated actually happened prior to invocation.

From the [Linux docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

> The function `dlerror()` returns a human readable string describing the
>   most recent error that occurred from `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` or `dlclose()`
>   since the last call to `dlerror()`. **It returns NULL if no errors have
>   occurred since initialization or since it was last called.**

In other words, your `dlopen` succeeded, so NULL is returned from `dlerror()`. That NULL is then sent as a `char *` to `std::cout`, and kerboom.

Bottom line: check your error conditions before invoking `dlerror()`. Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef void* (*fptr)();
    fptr func;

    void *handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    func = (fptr)dlsym(handle, "__libc_start_main");
    if (!func)
    {
        std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::cout << handle << " " << func << "\n";

    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is (likely) undefined behavior:

```
std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
```

...unless `dlerror` is actually non-null (which it probably isn't). It should be:

```
char* error = dlerror();
if (error != 0)
    std::cout << error << std::endl;
```

...or:

```
void *handle = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW); 
if (handle == 0)
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
```

Also, you probably should abort if `dlerror` is non-null (or `handle` is null), because calling `dlsym` on an null `handle` is also undefined behavior.

See [Why does std::cout output disappear completely after NULL is sent to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019454/why-does-stdcout-output-disappear-completely-after-null-is-sent-to-it).

Comment: Thank U. This is last problem how to do with member function. typedef void (A::*fptr)(); and than try something like func = (fptr)dlsym(handle, "test"); Than this is compile error because he dont know how to cast void to fptr. Can U help me with this?