# Is it possible to create an alias for std::cout?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using FText = std::string;
using Print = std::cout;

int main()
{
    FText Submission1 = 0;
    FText Submission2 = 0;
    FText Operator = "";

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I did:

```
using FText = std::string;
```

Why can I not make a substitution for `std::cout`? The error I get from the above code is: `"No type named 'cout' in namespace 'std'"`.

I am a beginner and I do not like typing all of `std::cout`. I managed to create an alias for `std::string`, but `cout` is not working.

I am using Xcode.

Comment: `cout` is an instance, not a type.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: You can't write the code like this, for the same reason you can't write `int a; using TA = a;`

Comment: you could do `auto& Print = std::cout;` but I don't recommend doing that. I would suggest getting used to typing it (it's only 3 characters longer than Print anyway). P.S: `FText Submission1 = 0;` is a pretty bad way to initialize a std::string (in fact im pretty sure its going to crash, at least [it does here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2025ff080aa7a1fc))

Comment: @Borgleader "_in fact im pretty sure its going to crash_" Undefined behavior is undefined. It might crash, it might not crash, or it might even produce expected results. Anything is possible with undefined behavior.

Comment: "change string", "change cout" These terms do not fit what you are doing, or are at best ambiguous. Please try to use full sentences to describe your goals. Cheers!

Comment: @Borgleader That's not really a crash, or at best it's a crash only because you didn't handle an exception. That being said, it's permitted to, because it's UB.

Comment: @Borgleader Kind of related, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019483/560648

Comment: Being lazy for typing is one big (if not the most frequent) cause for unneccessarily obfuscated code. Writing `std::cout` is the most concice and readable way of writing `std::cout`, consider that there are millions of c++ programmers and every one of them knows what `std::cout` means, but only you know what `Print` is

Comment: Why stop at `Print`? `P` is much less typing, your code will run faster too.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You are trying to make C++ look like your last language. That will stop you learning the proper way to use C++. Just bite the bullet and use the normal standard C++ types and objects. By using the standard types as is you will be able to get help from people that understand the language much more easily.

Comment: btw @MartinYork c++ is my first language i just think print or P would look alot better

Comment: @IsraelProductionzz Let me just state this is a really bad idea.

Comment: Legit use case: fast refactoring a prototype code that writes on an output file, to redirect the output to logs (cout is redirected to logs already for the rest of the code). the one liner auto &fs = std::cout is a great solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `using` or `typedef` to introduce a new name for a *type*.
`std::string` is a type, and these two are equivalent:

```
using FText = std::string;
typedef std::string FText;
```

But as the compiler says, `std::cout` is not a type (it's a variable).

You can introduce a new name for `std::cout` using a reference:

```
int main()
{
    auto& Print = std::cout;
    Print << "Hallo, Word!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like look of namespace specifiers, you can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    using std::cout;

    cout<< "Hallo, Word!";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new class say print class than override << insertion operator than use object of that class for printing.

```
class print{
public:
    int a;

    void operator<<(print &obj){
        cout<<obj.a<<endl;
    }

};

print obj;
obj.a =1;
obj<<obj;
```