# why I can't cout after using string tokenizer

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. While I was learning the `strtok()` function, I tried to `cout` after execution of the function, but I can't understand why the `cout` is not executing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<climits>
#include<string> 
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[100]="today is a rainy day";
    char *ptr=strtok(s," ");
    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        ptr=strtok(NULL," ");
        cout<<ptr<<endl;
    } 
    cout<<"Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand where this goes wrong.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ce5fb0f88afbb4a).

Comment: the cout<<hello after the while loop is not printing anything!!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Undefined behavior is a fickle mistress.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh yeah  libstdc++ happens to make it "safe" ([and sets an error flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019483/4386278))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sooner or later `ptr=strtok(NULL," ")` will return a null pointer. Which you *immediately* try to output leading to a null-pointer dereference and *undefined behavior* (and a very probable crash).

I suggest you modify your loop to something like this:

```
char *ptr = std::strtok(s, " ");
while (ptr != nullptr)
{
    std::cout << ptr << '\n';
    ptr = std::strtok(nullptr, " ");
}
```

Note the order in which things are done, and which guarantees that `ptr` will never be a null pointer when you output it.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while (ptr!=NULL)
```

to

```
while ((ptr = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
```

And erase the line with the call to `strtok`.

After `"day"` is printed, `ptr` is set to `"day"`, not `NULL`, so the next iteration of the loop is executed. But then `strtok` is called and `ptr` is set to `NULL`. Trying to `cout` with a NULL ptr is what gives you undefined behavior.

Should look like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<climits>
#include<string> 
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char s[100] = "today is a rainy day";
    char *ptr = strtok(s, " ");
    cout << ptr << endl;
    while ((ptr = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
        cout << ptr << endl;
    }

    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout`ing a `nullptr` will not 'give an error'. It gives the program undefined behaviour. Then it might seem to work correctly, give an error, read a poem, make toast, or infinite other things in between. One cannot rely on getting an error; one simply must avoid writing code that has UB.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<climits>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[100]="today is a rainy day";
    char *ptr=strtok(s," ");
    //cout<<ptr<<endl; // you can remove this line
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        cout<<ptr<<endl; // use cout upper the prt=strtok(NULL," "); 
        ptr=strtok(NULL," ");
        //cout<<ptr<<endl;  //problem here in your code.
    }
        cout<<"Hello There!";
        return 0;
}
```